# ASP.NET AJAX: How to access object properties?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp.net-ajax

My web method returns object 'User' that has a lot of properties.

In my 'OnComplete' function I am receiving those object.

```
function OnComplete(args) {
    var res = $get('WsResult');
    debugger;
    res.innerHTML = args['Nick'];
}
```

Question: How can I get values of object properties?

The code above provides me with '[object Object]' text instead of real object value.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get these properties the same way you get any other properties:

```
alert(args.Nick.FullName);
```